# limit_choice_to all objects of a particular model classe in a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

Example

```
class Base():
     pass

class A(Base)
parent=models.Foreignkey("self", limit_choices_to=(all members of the B class)

class B(Base)
parent=models.Foreignkey("self", limit_choices_to=(all members of the A class)
```

What would be the query syntax for limit_choices_to, to get only the
objects of a certain class?)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work instead ?

```
class Base(Model):
    parent=models.Foreignkey("self")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class A(Base):
    parent=models.Foreignkey("B")

class B(Base):
    parent=models.Foreignkey("A")
```

Comment: Yes, I don't think the OP's code would work at all - `self` is not `Base`, it is `A` or `B`.

Comment: You are right, the code I posted is wrong. What I want is something like sebplq's response (which I dont think works either because you cannot override child fields), but maintaining the parent foreign key and just filtering the available choices for the A and B classes. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: class Base(Model):
    parent=models.Foreignkey("self")
When you do this and inherit, self is Base, and A or B. What I want is to limit the choices to certain class name only for the admin.